# Why I'm getting error in swaping the letters/ reversing a word?

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def reverseWords(self, s: str) -> str:
        x = s.split(' ')
        z = []
        for i in x:
            l = 0
            r = len(i)-1
            while l <= r:
                i[l], i[r] = i[r], i[l]     
                #getting error: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
            z.append(i)
        return z

Can anyone help why I'm getting this error, because when I do :
```

*The code above I'm getting error, but the small code below I'm getting answer for this.*

```
     a = ['ab', 'io']
     b = ['bc', 'ko']
     a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
```

Comment: While a string is indexable, it doesn't support assigning to the indices because it is immutable.

Comment: Strings in python are immutable. You new to create a new string with values that you want.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you cannot assign into a string. But, you *can* with a `list`. You also need to update `l` and `r` so that your `while` loop is not infinite.

```
class Solution:
    def reverseWords(self, s: str) -> str:
        x = s.split(' ')
        z = []
        for i in x:
            chars = list(i)
            l=0
            r = len(chars) - 1
            while l <= r:
                chars[l], chars[r] = chars[r], chars[l]
                l += 1
                r -= 1    
            z.append(''.join(chars))
        return z
```